# How to split a string and keep the delimiters using boost::split?

Tags: c++, boost

I have a string like this:

```
std::string input("I #am going to# learn how #to use #boost# library#");
```

I do this:

```
std::vector<std::string> splitVector;
boost::split(splitVector, input, boost::is_any_of("#"));
```

And got this: (splitVector)

```
splitVector:
        "I "
        "am going to"
        " learn how " 
        "to use "
        "boos"
        " library"
        "" // **That's odd, why do I have an empty string here ?**
```

But need something like this:

```
splitVector:
    "I "
    "#am going to"
    "# learn how "
    "#to use "
    "#boost"
    "# library"
    "#"
```

How to do that ? Or maybe there is another way to do it in boost library ?
And why do I get an empty string in `splitVector` ?

Comment: Why do you need to keep the delimiters?

Comment: @gg.kaspersky, Good question! In result I have to restore the same string (build it up using splitVector), And I have a problem to detect  how many delimiters were in the string, odd or even number, in other words I always restore it as it has even number of delimiters. For instance: if I have the strings "#test" and "#test#"  and split it, get first string "test", and the same second string "test", and restore both strings as "#test#"

Comment: The empty string is there because the input string after the last delimiter is empty. Since your delimiter is a single char, you can simply prepend (or append) the char to result strings. If there were many different delimiters, I don't think boost split has the feature you need. See for example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511029/tokenize-a-string-and-include-delimiters-in-c) question for other solutions.

Comment: `split` on `"#test#"` should return `{"","test",""}`?

Comment: @edwin, I am not sure I properly understood your restore-string-use-case, but 1. you can build back the original string using join (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833447/a-good-example-for-boostalgorithmjoin) and 2. Number of '#' is equal to splitVector.size() - 1

Comment: if you only have one type of delimiter, why don't you add the delimiter after you have splitVector. somthing like splitVector[i]= strcat(#,splitVector[i])

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use `boost::split` because the internal implementation that uses the `split_iterator` from `boost/algorithm/string/find_iterator.hpp` swallows the tokens.

However you can get by with `boost::tokenizer`, as it has an option to keep the delimiters:

> Whenever a delimiter is seen in the input sequence, the current token is finished, and a new token begins. The delimiters in dropped_delims do not show up as tokens in the output whereas the delimiters in kept_delims do show up as tokens.
>  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/tokenizer/char_separator.htm

**[See next live:](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ee0726948cacb1c)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

int main() {
    // added consecutive tokens for illustration
    std::string text = "I #am going to# learn how ####to use #boost# library#";    
    boost::char_separator<char> sep("", "#"); // specify only the kept separators
    boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char>> tokens(text, sep);
    for (std::string t : tokens) { std::cout << "[" << t << "]" << std::endl; }
}
/* Output:
[I ]
[#]
[am going to]
[#]
[ learn how ]
[#]
[#]
[#]
[#]
[to use ]
[#]
[boost]
[#]
[ library]
[#] */
```